# Reading blob type image from mysql database in Spring mvc with jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

`ProductController.java`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminWelcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAdminWelcomePage(Model model) {

    System.out.println("Product List:" + productService.getAllProducts());

    model.addAttribute("productList", productService.getAllProducts());
    return "adminHomepage";
}
```

`ProductService.java`

```
 public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllProducts() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 3";

    List<Map<String, Object>> products = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
    return products;

}
```

Basically, this sql return the list of 3 products which are looks like 
`Product List:[{id=1, name=Twitter-minimal, userId=0, image=[B@96a7858, price=1213322.0, dateManufacture=2017-02-07, dateAdded=2017-02-07 15:50:12.0, category=Clothing, description=ramedadadadad}]`.

This is the sample of the result which I fetched from `MySql` database with `jdbcTemplate`. I upload the image using `Spring MVC4` in the database. Now I want to retrieve or read the `Blob`image type so that I can display those images to my jsp pages. How can I convert this Blob image so that I can properly display to pages?

The image type was defined as `MultipartFile image` in the domain class.

Answer (score 0):

yo need resource mapping in dispatcher-servlet.xml

and
add this in your jsp page..
where static as i have defined is /WEB-INF/assets/

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="/uploadedImages/**" location="#your image location eg:-C:/{your projectname}/uploadeImages/" />

Comment: <img src="<c:url value='/static/uploadedImages/${room.image}'/>" alt=" our rooms"/>